# Android - C++ compile errors in cygwin/android-ndk

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk, cygwin

Ive created a simple app to help me learn the ndk, jni, and get my c++ skills back up to par. However Im kind of stuck because Im getting some compile errors when I run ndk-build on my project from the cygwin command line. Its been a while since Ive used c++ to any extent so I know that my syntax is probably way off so if some one could help me clean this up or explain how I could do so then that would be awesome.....so heres my c++ code:

EDIT: latest code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Eigen/Dense>
#include <math.h>
#include <jni.h>

using namespace Eigen;

Vector3f vec;
Vector3f vec2;
Vector3f vecRtrn;


void vecLoad(float x, float y, float z, float x2, float y2, float z2){

vec(0) = x;
vec(1) = y;
vec(2) = z;
vec2(0) = x2;
vec2(1) = y2;
vec2(2) = z2;

}

void vecAdd(Vector3f vecA, Vector3f vecB){
vecRtrn = vecA+vecB;
}

extern "C"
{
JNIEXPORT jfloatArray JNICALL Java_jnimath_act_JnimathActivity_test
(JNIEnv *env, jobject obj, jfloatArray fltarray1, jfloatArray fltarray2){

float array1[3];

jfloatArray flt1 = fltarray1;
jfloatArray flt2 = fltarray2;

//flt1 = env->GetFloatArrayElements( fltarray1,0);
//flt2 = env->GetFloatArrayElements( fltarray2,0);


vecLoad(flt1[0], flt1[1], flt1[2], flt2[0], flt2[1], flt2[2]);
vecAdd(vec, vec2);

array1[0] = vecRtrn[0];
array1[1] = vecRtrn[1];
array1[2] = vecRtrn[2];

return array1;

};
}
```

Now Im pretty sure Im not using the correct way to return the array back to java through jni but thats a separate problem......but please feel free to comment on that as well ;)

Heres an updated list of the last couple of build errors I have.....its definitely a lot shorter than the original list :)

```
$ /cygdrive/c/android-ndk-r7/ndk-build
Compile++ thumb  : test <= test.cpp
jni/test.cpp: In function '_jfloatArray* Java_jnimath_act_JnimathActivity_test(JNIEnv*,  _jobject*, _jfloatArray*, _jfloatArray*)':
jni/test.cpp:42: error: cannot convert '_jfloatArray' to 'float' for argument '1' to      'void vecLoad(float, float, float, float, float, float)'
jni/test.cpp:49: error: cannot convert 'float*' to '_jfloatArray*' in return
make: *** [obj/local/armeabi/objs/test/test.o] Error 1
```

EDIT: heres my java code......

```
package jnimath.act;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class JnimathActivity extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */

public EditText x;
public EditText y;
public EditText z;

public EditText x2;
public EditText y2;
public EditText z2;

public float[] vecArray;

public TextView textView1;
public Button run;

float[] array3 = new float[3];
float[] array1 = new float[3];
  float[] array2 = new float[3];

  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    x = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.x);
    y = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.y);
    z = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.z);

    x2 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.x);
    y2 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.y);
    z2 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.z);




    textView1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    run = (Button)findViewById(R.id.run);

    run.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            array1[0] = Float.parseFloat(x.getText().toString());
            array1[1] = Float.parseFloat(y.getText().toString());
            array1[2] = Float.parseFloat(z.getText().toString());

            array2[0] = Float.parseFloat(x2.getText().toString());
            array2[1] = Float.parseFloat(y2.getText().toString());
            array2[2] = Float.parseFloat(z2.getText().toString());
            array3 = test(array1, array2);

            String text = array3[0]+" "+array3[1]+" "+array3[2];
            textView1.setText(text);

        }

      });

  }

  public native float[] test(float[] array1, float[] array2);

  static {
    System.loadLibrary("test");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error states, compiler does not like what you have in vecLoad. Are you sure Vector3f has correct '(' operator? I would check that first.

Comment: Hey thanks for commenting.....after looking at the eigen tutorials I figured I wasnt using the correct way to load the array so I changed it to the current code and the compiler likes it just fine. Now i just have to clean up the last couple of errors and then I can start trying to use my native methods in java :) But do you have any thoughts on the last couple errors?

Comment: @Jamesandresakis One thing I can notice is that env is a pointer but *env is value. But you use '->' that is usually for pointer.  And you can't do `float array1[];` in C/C++.

Comment: Yeah i picked that up from a jni tutorial....Im still not sure how to handle getting the parameters passed from java into native code using the jni. Most of the tutorials I found are kind of lacking one thing or another.

Comment: What about declaring a float array.....everywhere I look you declare an array in c++ like this..... int samp[2]; which would create an array with two spots in it.....at least thats what I always thought anway.

Comment: @Jamesandresakis post your java code as well. But judging from your comments, I recommend you study C/C++ more. You might get some help from here and there but your work will be frequently stopped due to your non-mastering. In addition, JNI is nothing but interface between C/C++ and java. You need to practice more to get used to it.

Comment: Ive posted my java code. I definitely need some polishing on my c++ skills being that the pointer and reference stuff is killing me at the moment.

Comment: @Jamesandresakis I just noticed that your file is cpp and in that case, you need to wrap your JINEXPORT c/c++ code with `extern "C" {` and `}`

Comment: :) yeah I wasnt sure if I needed that but Ill make sure to add it and see how it works.

Comment: @Jamesandresakis Please read the error. What does it tell you? As far as I can see, you are close. Figure it out by yourself. It's that simple.

Comment: Hey thanks for the help :) when I figure it all out and get it working Ill post everything back on here so other people with the same problem  have a decent example to go by.

Comment: Heres the solution I came up with from the help you guys gave me today :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8543221/android-a-simple-ndk-project-using-the-eigen-library-and-jni

Answer (score 1):

The first error is due to net specifying a size for `float array1[];`  Unlike java this isn't allowed.  You can on the other hand specify the array as `float *array1;` without initializing it.

The second and third error refer to you dereferencing your pointer before using the `->` operator.  The correct way to do it would be:

```
flt1 = env->GetFloatArrayElements(env, fltarray1, NULL);
flt2 = env->GetFloatArrayElements(env, fltarray2, NULL);
```

The last error you are just missing a number it looks like it should be `flt2[2]` instead of `flt[2]`.

Comment: Hey thanks for jumping in.....I went ahead and specified a size for the array like this....array1[3].....the compiler seems to like that just fine. I only need the array to hold 3 variables so declaring it is fine. Ill try implementing the code you suggested and post back.

Comment: that didnt seem to work either.....now i get the following error...... error: no matching function for call to '_JNIEnv::GetFloatArrayElements(JNIEnv*&, _jfloatArray*&, NULL)'

Comment: The call is different if you're on C vs C++.  In C it is the above, in C++ the call would be `env->GetFloatArrayElements(fltarray1, 0)`.  All the calls will be the same, just remove the `env` argument.

Comment: I implemented what you suggested and it got rid of errors related to that but now all i have left is the following.....jni/test.cpp:42: error: cannot convert '_jfloatArray' to 'float' for argument '1' to 'void vecLoad(float, float, float, float, float, float)'
jni/test.cpp:49: error: cannot convert 'float*' to '_jfloatArray*' in return

Comment: I just updated my last bit of c++ code and related build errors

Comment: @Jamesandresakis As Paul wrote below the errors will tell you everything you need to know.  It is a good idea to start dissecting them now.  In this case it is saying: Hey I don't know how to convert from a float to a jFloat.  These are not the same.  Reading a jni tutorial will explain how to get one from the other: [link](http://java.sun.com/developer/onlineTraining/Programming/JDCBook/jni.html)

Comment: Hey thanks for the help :) Ive been trying to figure out how to convert one to the other for a bit now. When I figure it out Ill post what I come up with so other people with the same problem have a simple example to go by.

Comment: Heres the solution I came up with from the help you guys gave me today :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8543221/android-a-simple-ndk-project-using-the-eigen-library-and-jni