# Android NDK pass array to c

Tags: android, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I just followed this [article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8543221/android-a-simple-ndk-project-using-the-eigen-library-and-jni). And now, I have this JNI code:

```
extern "C"{
   JNIEXPORT jfloatArray JNICALL Java_com_jp_algi_Corelib_vector
       (JNIEnv *env, jobject clazz, jfloatArray input){
        jfloat* flt1;
        flt1  = (*env)->GetFloatArrayElements(env, input, NULL);
        if (flt1 == NULL){
            return NULL; /* exception occurred */
        }
        // do stuff to the array
        (*env)->ReleaseFloatArrayElements(env, input, flt1, 0);
        return flt1;
        //delete flt1, v;
        //env->SetFloatArrayRegion(result, 0, 1, v);
    }
}
```

And for checking if its ok; I have in the Java code array,length check to log and its still sending back 44 512 array and isn't influenced by length of input array !! Its still same, I think I have some error in my `Application.mk`, because build its OK

`App.mk`:

```
  APP_ABI := all
  APP_STL := stlport_static
```

and `andr.mk` for sure:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(TOP_LOCAL_PATH)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE    := com_jp_algi_Corelib
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := com_jp_algi_Corelib.cpp, kiss_fft.c, kiss_fftr.c
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

OK my question is:

My JNI code doesn't work and I don't know why, because I don't understand in JNI, and C++!

Please, somebody tell my how I can re-write my code?

OK my task is:

- I would like to get Java array to C++ work only with array and return back to Java array

Comment: too much white space and not enough formatting in the code.

Comment: what is ReleaseIntArrayElements supposed to do with the jfloat* ?

Comment: OP: If you don't understand C++/JNI, why are you throwing yourself into the deep end? Get a basic understanding of C++ first prior to all of this...

Comment: becous i have to do it this . but thanks for help

Comment: and this isnt hard thing

Answer (score 2):

At first, you can't return jfloat* to Java. You lucky that this code doesn't crash JVM. At second, you can't use pointer to array (i mean jfloat*) after you call ReleaseFloatArrayElements because you return this array to JVM and it could move it or even delete

UPDATE ACORDING TASK

Usally I do it in this way.

```
extern "C" {
JNIEXPORT jboolean JNICALL Java_com_jp_algi_Corelib_vector
   (JNIEnv *env, jobject clazz, jfloatArray input){
    jfloat* flt1 = NULL;
    jsize size = env->GetArrayLength(input);
    // check if array size >0 and wedont cause exception
    if(size<=0) return(JNI_FALSE);
    if(env->ExceptionCheck()) {
#ifndef NDEBUG
      env->ExceptionDescribe();
#endif
      env->ExceptionClear();
      return(JNI_FALSE);
    }
    // allocate buffer for array and get data from Java array
    flt1  = new jfloat[size];
    env->GetFloatArrayRegion(input,0,size,flt1);
    // exception check. Always use exception check
    if(env->ExceptionCheck()) {
#ifndef NDEBUG
      env->ExceptionDescribe();
#endif
      env->ExceptionClear();
      delete[] flt1;
      return(JNI_FALSE);
    }
    // do stuff to the array
    // set result to Java array and delete buffer. And exception check of course
    env->SetFloatArrayRegion(input,0,size,flt1);
    delete[] flt1;
    if(env->ExceptionCheck()) {
#ifndef NDEBUG
      env->ExceptionDescribe();
#endif
      env->ExceptionClear();
      return(JNI_FALSE);
    }
    // All is ok
    return(JNI_TRUE);
}
}
```

It is better to use GetArrayRegions/SetArrayRegion becouse when you use GetFloatArrayElements you prevent original java array from moving in memmory. In some case it could cause OutOfMemoryException in other thtreads if there are some

P.S: I'm not sure that I didn't miss some brackets, sorry if it so

Comment: If you write your task, may be I could write correct source code

Comment: OK my task is: My JNI code doesnt work  and i dont why, becouse I dont understand in Deep in JNI , and c++ , pleas somebody tell my how i CAn re-writemy code?

Comment: sorry i thought you think question:) so task: OK my task is: I would like to get java array to c+ wokr only with array and return back to java array

Comment: And you should read some articles about C++ and JNI...